# Match value based on criteria in two columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have the following values in columns A, B and C.

```
A   B   C   D
3   3   5
4   4   10
```

In cell D1, how can I find the value in Column C where A=A+1 and B=B+1 i.e. 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like below?

```
=VLOOKUP(SUM(A1+1,B1+1),C:C,1,FALSE)
```